# svn export and revision in single command

Tags: bash, shell, svn

I am newbie in shell scripting.
I have an existing command in a script.

```
svn export --force "https://$svn_url/SVN_SOURCE_PATH" A_DIRECTORY
```

this command shows a lot of output and finally ends with below string

```
Exported revision 3779.
```

I want to capture and store this value (3779) in to a variable.
How can I do this.

Please avoid `svn info` or `svn export --force -r`

**UPDATE**

I tried below line

```
svn export --force "https://$svn_url/SVN_SOURCE_PATH" A_DIRECTORY | tail -n 1 | sed 's/Exported\ revision\ \([0-9][0-9]*\)\./\1/'
```

But the problem I face is, this line stopped showing the console messages.

Answer (score 0):

If the result is always in the last line

```
svn export --force "https://$svn_url/SVN_SOURCE_PATH" A_DIRECTORY | tail -n 1 | sed 's/Exported\ revision\ \([0-9][0-9]*\)\./\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matteo. But here the problem is there is no logs showing in console, that should not happen.

Comment: You should then edit you question and explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried below line
>
> ```
> svn export --force "https://$svn_url/SVN_SOURCE_PATH" A_DIRECTORY | tail -n 1 | sed 's/Exported\ revision\ \([0-9][0-9]*\)\./\1/'
> ```
>
> But the problem I face is, this line stopped showing the console
>   messages.

This copies the messages to *stderr* so that they still show, and assigns the value to `$revision`:

```
revision=`svn export --force…|tee /dev/fd/2|sed -n 's/Exported revision \([0-9]*\)./\1/p'`
```